# Pre-authentication failed: Errors

Tags: active-directory, kerberos, exchange-server

Recently we moved out our exchange server to a hosted company. I have noticed since than network user accounts keep getting locked in active directory. After some investigation it was found that outlook is generating kerbos pre-authentication and failing in the process and getting the user account locked. There are no problems apart from this in user experience and they can use outlook without problems(even when they are locked) and use other network resources.

What i wanted to ask is - a way for outlook to stop doing kerbos preauthentication?
or
If I disable the do not require Kerbos preauthentication in AD will that have any adverse affect?

Thanks a lot for your help in advance.

Regards
Raj

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed ip of server that you might have provided earlier somewhere in the configuration? As this seeems to be problem related to time before authentication, while looking for the server connection...I guess.

Comment: Thanks for replying shweta. I have created a new profile and deleted the old one in Outlook. So not sure where else it(IP) could have been saved.